# Error: Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,System.String]' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Tags: c#, sql, xml, linq

I have following code

```
    var doc = XDocument.Load(@"export.xml");
    var companiesList = new Companies();

    var companies = (from c in doc.Descendants("Company")
                        select c).ToList();
    foreach (var xCompany in companies)
    {
        var company = new Company()
        {
            Name = (from x in xCompany.Descendants("Name") select x.Value).ToString(),
            Code = (from x in xCompany.Descendants("Code") select x.Value).ToString(),
            MaintenancePercentage =
                Convert.ToDouble(from x in xCompany.Descendants("MaintenancePercentage") select x.Value)
        };
        companiesList.AllCompanies.Add(company);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(companies);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

currently companies has count 3000. I want to put each of those company in a list.

```
public class Companies
{
    public Companies()
    {
        AllCompanies = new List<Company>();
    }

    public List<Company> AllCompanies;
}

public class Company
{
    public string Name;
    public string Code;
    public double MaintenancePercentage;
    public double AverageSales;
    public double TotalSales;
    public double TotalMaintenanceFee;
    public List<Sales> Saleses;
}
```

Inside foreach statement i get error saying
Error: `Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,System.String]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.`

Any idea what i should do to make it work?

Here is sample xml code

```
<Companies>
    <Company>
    <Name>Name1</Name><Code>11014</Code>    
    <MaintenancePercentage>15.9</MaintenancePercentage>
     <Sales>
       <Sale>
       <Code>19538</Code>
       <Title>ABC</Title>
       <Date>2009-04-29T00:00:00</Date>
       <Category>Category1</Category>
       <Amount>6543.39</Amount>
       </Sale>
       <Sale>
       <Code>19539</Code>
       <Title>xyz</Title>
       <Date>2009-04-30T00:00:00</Date>
       <Category>Category2</Category>
       <Amount>654.39</Amount>
       </Sale>
    </Sales>
    </Company>

    <Company>
    <Name>Name1</Name><Code>11014</Code>     
<MaintenancePercentage>15.9</MaintenancePercentage>
     <Sales>
       <Sale>
       <Code>19538</Code>
       <Title>ABC</Title>
       <Date>2009-04-29T00:00:00</Date>
       <Category>Category1</Category>
       <Amount>6543.39</Amount>
       </Sale>
       <Sale>
       <Code>19539</Code>
       <Title>xyz</Title>
       <Date>2009-04-30T00:00:00</Date>
       <Category>Category2</Category>
       <Amount>654.39</Amount>
       </Sale>
    </Sales>
    </Company>
</Companies>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Convert.ToDouble((from x in xCompany.Descendants("MaintenancePercentage") select x.Value).First())
```

Why not use deserialization?

To answer more correctly it is necessary to see `XML`.

Comment: i think the problem also lies in converting string, how do i use deserialization?

Answer (score 0):

LINQ expression like

```
from x in xCompany.Descendants("Name") select x.Value
```

do not return a single object, so apply to result function like ToString or Convert.ToDouble is not entirely correct
to obtain a single value use this extensions methods:

- [First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.enumerable.first%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Single](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.enumerable.single%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [SingleOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)